# Can't figure out syntax error

Tags: wordpress

```
    <?php
if (have_posts()) {
while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>

 <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php}
}
     else{
         echo '<p>No Content Here</p>';
     }
?>
```

Every time i run this code just get

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Pro tip: always be careful with your code's indentation. That way you can see this kind of problem easily.

Comment: Above edited code by @Fast Snail,  Looks good. Are you still facing this error with new code?

Comment: No it's working good right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a space between "php" and closing bracket. It should be

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) { 
        the_post(); ?>
 <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php }
}
else {
    echo '<p>No Content Here</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah it's work 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid this

```
<?php}
```

Have a space

```
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing PHP with HTML usually produces obfuscation, and in your case obfuscation is leading to sintax errors.

I would have written:

```
<?php
  if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) { 
        the_post();
        echo '<h1>' . the_title() . '</h1>';
    }
  }
  else {
    echo '<p>No Content Here</p>';
  }
?>
```